# Azure Run as account across subscriptions

Tags: azure-automation

I have created an Azure Run as account in one of my subscriptions. In my PS runbook, how do I access resources in other subscriptions using this run as account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `run as account` essentially is a service principal in your azure ad tenant. When it was created under a subscription, it will be assigned a `Contributor` role under the subscription automatically.

If you want to let it access the resources in other subscriptions, just navigate to the specific subscription in the portal -> `Access control (IAM)` -> `Add` -> `Add role assignment` -> add the service principal(Display name of `run as account`) as a role which you want(e.g. Contributor). See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal). **Note**: Make sure your user account which used to login portal is an `Owner` role of the subscription, otherwise you will not have the permission to do that. For more details about azure RBAC, you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview).

Then in the runbook, you could use `Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"` to set the subscription to use, more details see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.profile/set-azurermcontext?view=azurermps-6.13.0).